# Example of an identification protocol that 1. With a private key 2. Resistant to attack with a fake ATM 3. Not resistant to eavesdropping attacks?

Tags: authentication

Can anyone please provide an example of an identification protocol that

1. With a private key
2. Resistant to attack with a fake ATM
3. Not resistant to eavesdropping attacks
   ?

Comment: You could eg use the private key to authenticate just the ATM I suppose....